# Trying to assign a value to a non l-value - AngularJs with colorpicker

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-1.7

I wrote code related to the color picker in `anguarjs 1.7.`. When I click to color picker to select next color it gives the error: `Trying to assign a value to a non l-value`

Here is my static code:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group" >
            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Category/Series 1</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="input-group colorpicker-component colorpicker-element col-sm-12 col-md-9" id="fontColorPicker">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="CustomColorPicker" ><i style="background-color: rgb(0, 128, 0);"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" id="CustomColorCode" value="#008000"  type="text" color-picker/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

got an answer to the above code. I was making a mistake by binding the wrong ng-modal to the color picker because of that I was facing this issue.